# appengine cloud storage compile error in demo project

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-storage

Following https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/googlecloudstorageclient/getstarted
fails when deploying

`goapp deploy -oauth`

with

`app.go:78: cannot use google.AppEngineContext(c) (type "golang.org/x/oauth2".Option) as type "github.com/golang/oauth2".Option in function argument`

I'm able to get the demo project to run by altering the import lines 33-34 in `google.golang.org/cloud/examples/storage/appengine/app.go` from

`"github.com/golang/oauth2"
"github.com/golang/oauth2/google"`

to

`"golang.org/x/oauth2"
"golang.org/x/oauth2/google"`

Most importantly, is this the right way to "fix" this (and should the demo project be / or have been updated by google?)
And if anyone has insight, if you could provide some context as to why there are (as it appears to me) multiple ways to refer to the same package that would be great as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the go subrepositories have been moved to `golang.org/x/...`

See the announcement: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/golang-nuts/eD8dh3T9yyA/l5Ail-xfMiAJ

The problem with identifying the canonical import path will be addressed in Go 1.4: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1jVFkZTcYbNLaTxXD9OcGfn7vYv5hWtPx9--lTx1gPMs

It seems there is indeed a problem with the examples. The oauth library refers to the `golang.org/x/...` paths with the recent [commit](https://github.com/golang/oauth2/commit/e750a2fd5a9df201dc09483a023db10cd797ec41).